# Bootstrap 4 Tooltip going out of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

While hovering on an anchor tag containing the tooltip attributes, the tooltip is position far away from the anchor tag.

LINK - **https://ewomenco.herokuapp.com/project/project-title/applicants**

Also on opening inspect element it goes too far.

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-title="Shortlist" title="shortlist"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>
```

**Attaching the screenshot.**

Stuck in it from a long time now. Tried positioning of parent div but nothing works.

Comment: What happens when you inspect that element? Is it showing the width and height larger than it actually is? Maybe a padding issue?

Comment: Actually there are 3 similar sections. the first 2 are coming correct but the last one is going out. Apart from that height, width and padding are correct. the problem is with the transform - translate property. It's giving arbitrary value to it.

Comment: What about the one that has the tooltip linked to it?

Comment: Check the new image i have uploaded

Comment: That doesn't look like it matches your code. Mind providing a JSFiddle of it or something? Hard to reproduce this.

Comment: hover on Thumbs up and take snapshot

Comment: @NikhilGhuse this is what is done!

And why people downvote i don't understand. It's an issue i am facing at other places also

Comment: try to make it a button or a span

Comment: try `$(function () {  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() })` if you still want a anchor tag

Comment: @NikhilGhuse the above js is to show the tooltip, which is not the problem. The problem is misalignment of the tooltip.
CharlieFish I Will provide the page where it's done.

Comment: okk just provide a sample

Comment: Check This - https://ewomenco.herokuapp.com/project/project-title/applicants

Comment: it is working as expected

Comment: @NikhilGhuse try it on the 3rd section

Comment: It is working on each of the section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Problem.

`html, body {
  height : 100%
}`

When i removed the height 100%, it worked as expected.

I feel sorry for the people who downvoted the question, without even looking at it.

Stay blessed!